# Changing Login Logo

Tags: login, logo

After modifying the code in my functions.php file to display a different logo on my login page, I'm getting a blank square instead.

I've added a custom .png image (326x67) to my (child) theme's image folder, and the code I've added to `functions.php` is as follows:

```
function custom_loginlogo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    h1 a {background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/login_logo.png) !important; }
    </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_loginlogo');
```

Could it be a permissions problem (like an `.htaccess` file blocking the image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a child theme then maybe you should try the following code. Not necessary to put `!important` too unless some other plugin or code is overwriting it.

```
function custom_loginlogo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    h1 a { background-image: url('.  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/login_logo.png); }
    </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_loginlogo');
```

Comment: for extra up votes, could you explain why this fixes the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use something like this and just edit the css depending on how the logo looks:

Added into `functions.php`

```
/** Change Login Image **/
function my_login_logo() { 
    if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.png'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.png';
    else if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.jpg'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.jpg';
    else if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/logo.gif'))
        $logo = '/images/logo.gif';
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.login div#login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').$logo; ?>);
            background-size: auto;
            width: 330px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-bottom: -15px;
            margin-left: -4%;
        }
    </style>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it at the bottom of your theme function.php file before closing php sign `?>` (if there is one).

```
function change_my_wp_login_image() {
   echo ”
   <style>
   body.login #login h1 a {
   background: url(‘”.get_bloginfo(‘template_url’).”/images/your_image_name‘) 8px 0 no-repeat transparent;
   background-position:center;
   height:100px;
   width:320px;
   background-color:#E48C07;
}
</style>
“;
}
add_action(“login_head”, “change_my_wp_login_image”);

//logo url website
// verander de url op de login pagina
function put_my_url(){
   return (‘your_website_URL‘);
}
add_filter(‘login_headerurl’, ‘put_my_url’);

// changing the login page URL hover text
function put_my_title(){
   return (‘Your_Website_title‘);
}
add_filter(‘login_headertitle’, ‘put_my_title’);
```

Comment: The quotes are messed up - will break the code. Also some of your comments are not in English and only a minority will understand them. Then there's the **problem** that some of your brackets are misplaced, etc.